# HtmlUnit error when trying to connect a webpage

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I just heard about this `HtmlUnit` thing today when I was trying to figure out how to dump the source code of a website. What I am trying to do is use a script to dump the source code from a website but when I run it  get a nice long list of red.

This is the code im using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {

    String url = "http://www.runelocus.com/forums/member.php?102785&tab=aboutme#aboutme";
    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
    HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);
    System.out.println(page.getWebResponse().getContentAsString());
}
```

This is the errors im getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:822)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:152)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1439)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1358)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:358)
at HTMLDumping.htmlunittest.main(htmlunittest.java:18)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Invalid header: blcc_proxy
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parseHeaders(AbstractMessageParser.java:224)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:645)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
```

If anyone might know how to fix this please suggest something. All feedback accepted.

Comment: Are you intending to use `HTMLUnit` for testing purposes or are you trying to `scrape` the website? If you simply want to `scrape` the website then [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Use: System.out.println(page.asText());